# Log4j2 with Slf4 along with Spring Boot initializes well, but don't log anything else

Tags: spring-boot, slf4j, log4j2

I moved to Spring Boot recently and was using log4j2 along with Sl4j which was working perfectly fine. After I made lot of changes using Feign, hystrix and Spring cloud libraries, at some point log4j logging was broken. My first attempt was to remove those fancy spring cloud libraries i added, but unfortunately that didn't fix the issue. I am seeing some weird stuff during deployment and initializing the logging context. Below is my trace.

```
   Initializing configuration XmlConfiguration[location=/com/config/my-service/log4j2.xml]
   2016-12-05 15:10:33,748 main DEBUG Installed script engines
   2016-12-05 15:10:34,403 main DEBUG Oracle Nashorn Version: 1.8.0_25, Language: ECMAScript, Threading: Not Thread Safe, Compile: true, Names: {nashorn, Nashorn, js, JS, JavaScript, javascript, ECMAScript, ecmascript}
   2016-12-05 15:10:34,404 main DEBUG PluginManager 'Core' found 101 plugins
   2016-12-05 15:10:34,404 main DEBUG PluginManager 'Level' found 0 plugins
   2016-12-05 15:10:34,413 main DEBUG Starting 1 Log4j2Scheduled threads
   2016-12-05 15:10:34,418 main DEBUG Building Plugin[name=property, class=org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.Property].
   2016-12-05 15:10:34,456 main TRACE TypeConverterRegistry initializing.
   2016-12-05 15:10:34,457 main DEBUG PluginManager 'TypeConverter' found 23 plugins
   2016-12-05 15:10:34,472 main DEBUG createProperty(name="log-path", value="/com/logs")
   2016-12-05 15:10:34,473 main DEBUG Building Plugin[name=property, class=org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.Property].
   2016-12-05 15:10:34,474 main DEBUG createProperty(name="module", value="my-service")
   2016-12-05 15:10:34,474 main DEBUG Building Plugin[name=properties, class=org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.PropertiesPlugin].
   2016-12-05 15:10:34,483 main DEBUG configureSubstitutor(={log-path=/com/logs, module=my-service}, Configuration(SERVICE))
   2016-12-05 15:10:34,484 main DEBUG PluginManager 'Lookup' found 14 plugins
   2016-12-05 15:10:34,486 main DEBUG Building Plugin[name=layout, class=com.mycompany.logging.jsonlayout.log4j2.MycompanyJsonLayout].
   2016-12-05 15:10:34,487 main DEBUG createLayout(pretty="true", layoutVersion="2", showOrigin="false")
   2016-12-05 15:10:34,894 main DEBUG Building Plugin[name=SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy, class=org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.rolling.SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy].
   2016-12-05 15:10:34,897 main DEBUG createPolicy(size="100 MB")
   2016-12-05 15:10:34,899 main DEBUG Building Plugin[name=Policies, class=org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.rolling.CompositeTriggeringPolicy].
   2016-12-05 15:10:34,900 main DEBUG createPolicy(={SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy(size=104857600)})
   2016-12-05 15:10:34,900 main DEBUG Building Plugin[name=DefaultRolloverStrategy, class=org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.rolling.DefaultRolloverStrategy].
   2016-12-05 15:10:34,902 main DEBUG createStrategy(max="1", min="null", fileIndex="null", compressionLevel="null", ={}, stopCustomActionsOnError="true", Configuration(SERVICE))
   2016-12-05 15:10:34,904 main DEBUG Building Plugin[name=appender, class=org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.RollingFileAppender].
   2016-12-05 15:10:34,908 main DEBUG createAppender(fileName="/com/logs/my-service.json", filePattern="/com/logsmy-service.json.%i.gz", append="null", name="comjson", bufferedIO="null", bufferSize="null", immediateFlush="null", Policies(CompositeTriggeringPolicy(policies=[SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy(size=104857600)])), DefaultRolloverStrategy(DefaultRolloverStrategy(min=1, max=1)), MycompanyJsonLayout(com.mycompany.logging.jsonlayout.log4j2.MycompanyJsonLayout@41ee392b), Filter=null, ignoreExceptions="null", advertise="null", advertiseURI="null", Configuration(SERVICE))
   2016-12-05 15:10:34,914 main DEBUG Starting RollingFileManager /com/logs/my-service.json
   2016-12-05 15:10:34,914 main DEBUG PluginManager 'FileConverter' found 2 plugins
   2016-12-05 15:10:34,915 main DEBUG Building Plugin[name=appenders, class=org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AppendersPlugin].
   2016-12-05 15:10:34,916 main DEBUG createAppenders(={comjson})
   2016-12-05 15:10:34,917 main DEBUG Building Plugin[name=AppenderRef, class=org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AppenderRef].
   2016-12-05 15:10:34,918 main DEBUG createAppenderRef(ref="comjson", level="null", Filter=null)
   2016-12-05 15:10:34,918 main DEBUG Building Plugin[name=logger, class=org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.LoggerConfig].
   2016-12-05 15:10:34,927 main DEBUG createLogger(additivity="false", level="DEBUG", name="com.mycompany.ecommerce", includeLocation="null", ={comjson}, ={}, Configuration(SERVICE), Filter=null)
   2016-12-05 15:10:34,931 main DEBUG Building Plugin[name=logger, class=org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.LoggerConfig].
   2016-12-05 15:10:34,933 main DEBUG createLogger(additivity="true", level="DEBUG", name="com.mycompany.service.interceptor", includeLocation="null", ={}, ={}, Configuration(SERVICE), Filter=null)
   2016-12-05 15:10:34,933 main DEBUG Building Plugin[name=logger, class=org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.LoggerConfig].
   2016-12-05 15:10:34,935 main DEBUG createLogger(additivity="true", level="DEBUG", name="com.com", includeLocation="null", ={}, ={}, Configuration(SERVICE), Filter=null)
   2016-12-05 15:10:34,936 main DEBUG Building Plugin[name=logger, class=org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.LoggerConfig].
   2016-12-05 15:10:34,937 main DEBUG createLogger(additivity="true", level="INFO", name="performance", includeLocation="null", ={}, ={}, Configuration(SERVICE), Filter=null)
   2016-12-05 15:10:34,938 main DEBUG Building Plugin[name=logger, class=org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.LoggerConfig].
   2016-12-05 15:10:34,939 main DEBUG createLogger(additivity="true", level="INFO", name="com.mycompany.ecommerce.health", includeLocation="null", ={}, ={}, Configuration(SERVICE), Filter=null)
   2016-12-05 15:10:34,939 main DEBUG Building Plugin[name=AppenderRef, class=org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AppenderRef].
   2016-12-05 15:10:34,940 main DEBUG createAppenderRef(ref="comjson", level="null", Filter=null)
   2016-12-05 15:10:34,941 main DEBUG Building Plugin[name=root, class=org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.LoggerConfig$RootLogger].
   2016-12-05 15:10:34,942 main DEBUG createLogger(additivity="null", level="INFO", includeLocation="null", ={comjson}, ={}, Configuration(SERVICE), Filter=null)
   2016-12-05 15:10:34,942 main DEBUG Building Plugin[name=loggers, class=org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.LoggersPlugin].
   2016-12-05 15:10:34,944 main DEBUG createLoggers(={com.mycompany.ecommerce, com.mycompany.service.interceptor, com.com, performance, com.mycompany.ecommerce.health, root})
   2016-12-05 15:10:34,946 main DEBUG Configuration XmlConfiguration[location=/com/config/my-service/log4j2.xml] initialized
   2016-12-05 15:10:34,946 main DEBUG Starting configuration XmlConfiguration[location=/com/config/my-service/log4j2.xml]
   2016-12-05 15:10:34,948 main DEBUG Started configuration XmlConfiguration[location=/com/config/my-service/log4j2.xml] OK.
   2016-12-05 15:10:34,957 main TRACE Stopping org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.DefaultConfiguration@87aac27...
   2016-12-05 15:10:34,957 main TRACE DefaultConfiguration notified 1 ReliabilityStrategies that config will be stopped.
   2016-12-05 15:10:34,958 main TRACE DefaultConfiguration stopping root LoggerConfig.
   2016-12-05 15:10:34,958 main TRACE DefaultConfiguration notifying ReliabilityStrategies that appenders will be stopped.
   2016-12-05 15:10:34,958 main TRACE DefaultConfiguration stopping remaining Appenders.
   2016-12-05 15:10:34,959 main DEBUG Shutting down OutputStreamManager SYSTEM_OUT.false.false-1
   2016-12-05 15:10:34,959 main TRACE DefaultConfiguration stopped 1 remaining Appenders.
   2016-12-05 15:10:34,960 main TRACE DefaultConfiguration cleaning Appenders from 1 LoggerConfigs.
   2016-12-05 15:10:34,960 main DEBUG Stopped org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.DefaultConfiguration@87aac27 OK
   2016-12-05 15:10:35,019 main TRACE Reregistering MBeans after reconfigure. Selector=org.apache.logging.log4j.core.selector.ClassLoaderContextSelector@15761df8
   2016-12-05 15:10:35,020 main TRACE Reregistering context (1/1): '5b2133b1' org.apache.logging.log4j.core.LoggerContext@6ab7a896
   2016-12-05 15:10:35,023 main TRACE Unregistering but no MBeans found matching 'org.apache.logging.log4j2:type=5b2133b1'
   2016-12-05 15:10:35,023 main TRACE Unregistering but no MBeans found matching 'org.apache.logging.log4j2:type=5b2133b1,component=StatusLogger'
   2016-12-05 15:10:35,024 main TRACE Unregistering but no MBeans found matching 'org.apache.logging.log4j2:type=5b2133b1,component=ContextSelector'
   2016-12-05 15:10:35,024 main TRACE Unregistering but no MBeans found matching 'org.apache.logging.log4j2:type=5b2133b1,component=Loggers,name=*'
   2016-12-05 15:10:35,025 main TRACE Unregistering but no MBeans found matching 'org.apache.logging.log4j2:type=5b2133b1,component=Appenders,name=*'
   2016-12-05 15:10:35,025 main TRACE Unregistering but no MBeans found matching 'org.apache.logging.log4j2:type=5b2133b1,component=AsyncAppenders,name=*'
   2016-12-05 15:10:35,026 main TRACE Unregistering but no MBeans found matching 'org.apache.logging.log4j2:type=5b2133b1,component=AsyncLoggerRingBuffer'
   2016-12-05 15:10:35,026 main TRACE Unregistering but no MBeans found matching 'org.apache.logging.log4j2:type=5b2133b1,component=Loggers,name=*,subtype=RingBuffer'
   2016-12-05 15:10:35,029 main DEBUG Registering MBean org.apache.logging.log4j2:type=5b2133b1
   2016-12-05 15:10:35,038 main DEBUG Registering MBean org.apache.logging.log4j2:type=5b2133b1,component=StatusLogger
   2016-12-05 15:10:35,040 main DEBUG Registering MBean org.apache.logging.log4j2:type=5b2133b1,component=ContextSelector
   2016-12-05 15:10:35,043 main DEBUG Registering MBean org.apache.logging.log4j2:type=5b2133b1,component=Loggers,name=
   2016-12-05 15:10:35,044 main DEBUG Registering MBean org.apache.logging.log4j2:type=5b2133b1,component=Loggers,name=performance
   2016-12-05 15:10:35,044 main DEBUG Registering MBean org.apache.logging.log4j2:type=5b2133b1,component=Loggers,name=com.com
   2016-12-05 15:10:35,044 main DEBUG Registering MBean org.apache.logging.log4j2:type=5b2133b1,component=Loggers,name=com.mycompany.ecommerce
   2016-12-05 15:10:35,045 main DEBUG Registering MBean org.apache.logging.log4j2:type=5b2133b1,component=Loggers,name=com.mycompany.service.interceptor
   2016-12-05 15:10:35,045 main DEBUG Registering MBean org.apache.logging.log4j2:type=5b2133b1,component=Loggers,name=com.mycompany.ecommerce.health
   2016-12-05 15:10:35,047 main DEBUG Registering MBean org.apache.logging.log4j2:type=5b2133b1,component=Appenders,name=comjson
   2016-12-05 15:10:35,052 main TRACE Using default SystemClock for timestamps.
   2016-12-05 15:10:35,052 main TRACE Using DummyNanoClock for nanosecond timestamps.
   2016-12-05 15:10:35,053 main DEBUG Reconfiguration complete for context[name=5b2133b1] at URI /com/config/my-service/log4j2.xml (org.apache.logging.log4j.core.LoggerContext@6ab7a896) with optional ClassLoader: null
   2016-12-05 15:10:35,053 main DEBUG Shutdown hook enabled. Registering a new one.
   2016-12-05 15:10:35,054 main DEBUG LoggerContext[name=5b2133b1, org.apache.logging.log4j.core.LoggerContext@6ab7a896] started OK.
   2016-12-05 15:10:35,991 main DEBUG Using configurationFactory org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.ConfigurationFactory$Factory@35047d03
```

I am so curious about the Unregistering mBeans. Because my Appenders are unregistered. Also below this one makes no sense to me!

```
    TRACE Stopping       org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.DefaultConfiguration@87aac27...
  2016-12-05 15:10:34,957 main TRACE DefaultConfiguration notified 1 ReliabilityStrategies that config will be stopped.
  2016-12-05 15:10:34,958 main TRACE DefaultConfiguration stopping root LoggerConfig.
  2016-12-05 15:10:34,958 main TRACE DefaultConfiguration notifying ReliabilityStrategies that appenders will be stopped.
  2016-12-05 15:10:34,958 main TRACE DefaultConfiguration stopping remaining Appenders.
  2016-12-05 15:10:34,959 main DEBUG Shutting down OutputStreamManager SYSTEM_OUT.false.false-1
  2016-12-05 15:10:34,959 main TRACE DefaultConfiguration stopped 1 remaining Appenders.
  2016-12-05 15:10:34,960 main TRACE DefaultConfiguration cleaning Appenders from 1 LoggerConfigs.
  2016-12-05 15:10:34,960 main DEBUG Stopped org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.DefaultConfiguration
```

I EXCLUDED unnecessary logging related libraries from my class path like commons-logging, jul-to-slf4j, log4j-over-slf4j and logback stuff.

I do have following jars in my classpath

1. jcl-over-slf4j: 1.7.21
2. jboss-logging: 3.3.0.Final
3. log4j-api: 2.6.2
4. log4j-core: 2.6.2
5. log4j-slf4j-impl: 2.6.2
6. log4j-web: 2.4
7. spring-boot-starter-log4j2: 1.4.1.RELEASE
8. spring-boot-starter-logging:1.4.1.RELEASE

All i see is below in my my-service.json file

```
{
 "time" : "2016-12-05T21:22:08.742Z",
 "service" : { },
 "message" : {
   "category" : "org.eclipse.jetty.util.log",
   "severity" : "INFO",
   "text" : "Logging initialized @2227ms"
 },
 "v" : "2"
}
```

Can someone please help me with whats going on here? I see INFO logs in my console too. But appenders doesn't seems to be working.

Answer (score 0):

-D option I was using was -Dlog4j.ConfigurationFile.  One of the jars pulled in clashes with spring boot configurations. Using -Dlogging.config option of spring boot solved the issue.

Comment: Did you find out anything about which jar was clashing with the Spring Boot configurations?